Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{24n^3 - 4n^2 - 9n + 3}{n^2 (2n-1)^2 (n+1)}$ converges to 11
I am studying the following infinite series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{24n^3 - 4n^2 - 9n + 3}{n^2 (2n-1)^2 (n+1)}$$
Numerical approximations suggest that this series converges to a value very close to 11. However, I am unable to provide a formal proof of this result. Using numerical computations, I calculated partial sums for increasingly large $n$:

for $n = 100$, $\approx 10.76$,
for $n = 200$, $\approx 10.79$,
for $n = 500$, $\approx 10.81$,

and so on. Using high-precision arithmetic, the partial sums approach 11 but do not seem to reach it exactly, likely due to numerical limitations.
Could someone provide guidance or an analytical approach to prove that this series converges to 11? Any suggestions — whether through known summation techniques, connections to other series, or asymptotic analysis — would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and insights!

Actually, the sum is $\frac{2}{9} \left(8+3 \pi ^2+8 \log (4)\right)\approx10.822$.

"I  am studying the following infinite series" : what does this mean?  Is this a problem that you were assigned from a class/book?  If so, which specific class/book?  If not, if this is simply a problem that you are attacking outside of a class/book, why are you studying this series?  The point behind these questions is to identify what training that you have received that is pertinent to the specific problem.   ...see next comment

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

One's instinct should tell that this sum can't be 11. Why didn't OP check it on Mathematica? The denominator has root 0, 1/2 degree 2 and root -1 degree 1, these are enough to tell that closed form should contain $\pi$ and $\log(\cdot)$.

@QuýNhân One develops that level of mathematical intuition over time when studying specific types of problems. Perhaps OP didn't think to check the full sum, or maybe they were using something other than WolframAlpha. Regardless, disparaging the OP for something that was obvious to you is misguided. I think OP's curiosity should be encouraged, even if it led them to an incorrect conclusion here.

This seems like a case for partial fractions.

@teadawg1337 You are right, maybe I was too harsh with that "instinct" word, but I genuinely didn't mean to discourage him.

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{24n^3 - 4n^2 - 9n + 3}{n^2 (2n-1)^2 (n+1)}$$
Perform partial fractions,
$$\color{blue}{\frac{24 n^{3} - 4 n^{2} - 9 n + 3}{n^{2} \left(n + 1\right) \left(2 n - 1\right)^{2}}=\frac{3}{n^{2}}+\frac{\frac{32}{9}}{2 n - 1}+\frac{\frac{4}{3}}{\left(2 n - 1\right)^{2}}+\frac{- \frac{16}{9}}{n + 1}}$$
$$\frac{24 n^{3} - 4 n^{2} - 9 n + 3}{n^{2} \left(n + 1\right) \left(2 n - 1\right)^{2}}=3\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{32}{3}\frac{1}{(2 n - 1)(2n+2)}+\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{\left(2 n - 1\right)^{2}}$$
$$S=3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{32}{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2 n - 1)(2n+2)}+\frac{4}{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(2 n - 1\right)^{2}}$$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{2}} = \zeta(2)$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2 n - 1)(2n+2)}=\frac{\log(2)}{3}+\frac16$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\left(2 n - 1\right)^{2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$


$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{24n^3 - 4n^2 - 9n + 3}{n^2 (2n-1)^2 (n+1)}=\frac{2}{3}\pi^2+\frac{16}{9}+\frac{32}{9}\log(2)}$$
$$S\approx 10.822<11$$
Useful References

Reference 1

Reference 2

Reference 3

Reference 4

Reference 5

Reference 6

Reference 7

Reference 8

Reference 9



I think you should do that combine step immediately, writing divergent sums like that is illegal.

Could you please explain how to evaluate the second series?

@DavideMasi Reference 6 + partial sums then I applied this

Since it looks like you are new to these stuff, I would like to make a quick review for you about Infinite Series.
Check out Partial fraction along with Gauss's digamma theorem and special values of PolyGamma. Or if you sum over all integers, you can use Residue theorem or this specific technique (proved by inverse Laplace transform):
$$f_{a,b}(n)=\frac{e^{ibn}}{(an)^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}e^{in(ax+b)}dx$$
This has the advantage of being multiplicative in case you have multiple cells of $f_{a,b}(n)$. Combine this with Dirac comb: $\sum_{k=-N}^{N}e^{iky}\to2\pi\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(y-2\pi k)$ (where $\delta(x)$ is Delta Dirac distribution) can produce geometric sums. One example is here
One special trick is that you can "modify" the sum so that you can sum over all integers, for example:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{h^2}+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+h^2}\right)$$
Also, there are a lot of beautiful sums on MSE here, this is one of my favorites
Personal advice: Don't trust numerical results that way. Please consider using Mathematica. Your sum's value is $\frac{2}{9}(8+3\pi^2+8\log(4))=10.822...$, not $11$.

Let $A:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$ and $B:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n=\ln2.$
$$\frac{24n^3-4n^2-9n+3}{n^2(2n-1)^2(n+1)}=\frac3{n^2}+\frac{4/3}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{32}9\left(\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n+2}\right)$$
hence
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{24n^3-4n^2-9n+3}{n^2(2n-1)^2(n+1)}&=3A+\frac43\left(A-\frac A4\right)+\frac{32}9\left(B+\frac12\right)\\&=4A+\frac{32}9B+\frac{16}9\\
&=\frac{2\pi^2}3+\frac{32}9\ln2+\frac{16}9\\&\approx10.822.
\end{align}$$

Much better than the accepted answer. (+1)

You could even have a good approximation of the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac{24n^3 - 4n^2 - 9n + 3}{n^2 (2n-1)^2 (n+1)}$$
After partial fraction decomposition, you have a sum of polygamma functions and using their asymptotics
$$S_p=\frac{2}{9} \left(8+3 \pi ^2+16 \log (2)\right)-\frac{6}{p}+\frac{7}{2 p^2}-\frac{9}{4 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ which is in a relative error smaller than  $0.10$% if $p=4$ and smaller than  $0.01$% if $p=7$.
